# Javascript AutoScroll Loop Div Content

Tags: javascript

I have [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cr1wqvd/) and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the content not have the gap when auto scrolling. Basically when the content reaches the bottom I want the loop to restart immediately so there is not a large gap between showing the divs again. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Code I am using is

```
function autoScroll(){
var top = parseInt($(".inner").css("top").replace("px",""));
var height = $(".outer").outerHeight();
if(top <  height) {
   $(".inner").animate({"top":height},25000,autoScroll)           
}
else {
    $(".inner").css({"top":-height});
    autoScroll();
} 
}
autoScroll();
```

Comment: What you need to do is to cut the first `h3` the scroll out (which is actually the last h3 in the list) and then put it as the first one. 
I am trying to work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could duplicate the contents of `.inner`, keeping the outer height unchanged, so that half of the content is hidden. Then animate such that at every cycle of height movement, you jump back. Because of the repeated content, this jump will not be apparent:

```js
function autoScrollDown(){
    $(".inner").css({top:-$(".outer").outerHeight()}) // jump back
               .animate({top:0},5000,"linear", autoScrollDown); // and animate
}
function autoScrollUp(){
    $(".inner").css({top:0}) // jump back
               .animate({top:-$(".outer").outerHeight()},5000,"linear", autoScrollUp); // and animate
}
// fix hight of outer:
$('.outer').css({maxHeight: $('.inner').height()});
// duplicate content of inner:
$('.inner').html($('.inner').html() + $('.inner').html());
autoScrollUp();
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.inner{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}
.outer{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <h3>Scrolling down... line 3</h3>
        <h3>Scrolling down... line 2</h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
        <h3> Scrolling down... line 1 </h3> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can the scrolling be reversed so it appears as a content is scrolling up?

Comment: Sure, I added a second function, so now you have `autoScrollDown` and `autoScrollUp`. The snippet runs the second one now.

Comment: This is great. How is the best way to implement this but have it stop when the user manually scrolls in any direction?

Comment: @knutagard, please ask your question as a new question and include your code, where you are stuck, what is the expected behaviour,...etc.